# HSQLDB throws Asset failed exception and file io error on db.script.new file during Checkpoint

Tags: hsqldb, hypersql

Our application is a Java based desktop application which will download the binary data from the source, parses it and add it to HSQLDB database.  When downloading from the sources individually, application works perfectly. But when doing the same from multiple sources simultaneously with each source in an individual thread, I am getting an error of

```
java.sql.SQLException: Assert failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 23 in statement [CHECKPOINT]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

or sometimes,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Assert failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1016 in statement [CHECKPOINT]
```

followed by

```
java.sql.SQLException: File input/output error: C:\ProgramData\test\data\database\db.script.new in statement [CHECKPOINT]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Java: 1.8; 
HSQL version: 1.8.10

We are not in the position to migrate the HSQLDB to latest version because of various reasons.

HSQL Properties:

```
hsqldb.script_format=0
runtime.gc_interval=0
sql.enforce_strict_size=false
hsqldb.cache_size_scale=8
readonly=false
hsqldb.nio_data_file=true
hsqldb.cache_scale=14
version=1.8.0
hsqldb.default_table_type=memory
hsqldb.cache_file_scale=1
hsqldb.log_size=200
modified=yes
hsqldb.cache_version=1.7.0
hsqldb.original_version=1.8.0
hsqldb.compatible_version=1.8.0
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an 7 year old version which is not ideal for multi-threaded usage.

The simple solution is to perform the database updates with a single thread. You can retrofit your multi-threaded application with a `synchronized` block over a singleton object around the code that performs the database update.